# How looks the "land of Tamagawa numbers"?

Tags: arithmetic-geometry, ag.algebraic-geometry, zeta-functions

Jonah Sinick's question [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/5611/the-class-number-formula-the-bsd-conjecture-and-the-kronecker-limit-formula), other interesting ideas he mentioned, and Franz Lemmermeyer's [remark](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/5611/the-class-number-formula-the-bsd-conjecture-and-the-kronecker-limit-formula/20244#20244) make one think at Bloch and Kato's [drawing + question](http://books.google.com/books?id=_BnSoQSKnNUC&pg=PA336&lpg=PA336&dq=%22land+of+Tamagawa+numbers%22&source=bl&ots=hRYmM6u8GU&sig=q5t6bdFHKKXIv95ITjDW5eGzxN8&hl=en&ei=Mt7zS9qdPNKksAbfpYmGDA&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=1&ved=0CAkQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=%22land%20of%20Tamagawa%20numbers%22&f=false). What's known or guessed about that "land" by now and how would a new map look like?

Comment: Is this a question or a riddle?

Comment: Is that a question or a 'Catch (2pi*i)'? :))   