# Second derivative at 1 of L function of elliptic curve

Tags: nt.number-theory, elliptic-curves, l-functions

Let $E$ be an elliptic curve over $\mathbb Q$ of conductor $N$ and rank $0$. It follows from the functional equation that
$$L'(E,1)=(\log(2\pi/\sqrt{N})+\gamma)L(E,1)$$
where $\gamma$ is Euler's constant and $L(E,1)$ is given by BSD.

Can anything interesting be said about $L''(E,1)$ ?

Comment: This looks like an eigenvalue for the differential operator that maps a function to its derivative at 1.

Comment: @SylvainJULIEN The operation you mention sends a function to a number. It doesn't make sense to speak of its eigenvalues.

Comment: If $i$ is odd then the $i$-th derivative of the completed $L$-function $\Lambda(E,s)$ vanishes at $s=1$. Taking $i=3$ one gets a relation, but it seems it will involve the $j$-th derivatives for every $0 \leq j \leq i$.

Comment: The same idea will link the first two coefficients of $L$ together even for higher order vanishing. I guess you are hoping for a number field analogue of the work of Zhiwei Yun and Wei Zhang, but I guess this is outside of reach currently.

Comment: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/105190/power-series-expansions-of-l-series  is related